# SQL query to select most recent of duplicates and maximum value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have Customer table below

```
ID|Cust_ID|Name|Amount|  PaidDate
 1|     01|Tina|   100|2018-03-07
 2|     02|Lisa|    50|2018-03-05
 3|     01|Tina|   180|2018-03-07
 4|     01|Tina|    20|2018-03-01
```

So current query I have is selecting records with recent date:

```
select ID, Name, Amount, PaidDate from Customer C1
where PaidDate in ( select max(PaidDate) from Customer C2
where C1.ID=C2.ID)
```

The Result looks like this

```
ID|Cust_ID|Name|Amount|  PaidDate
 1|     01|Tina|   100|2018-03-07
 2|     02|Lisa|    50|2018-03-05
 3|     01|Tina|   180|2018-03-07
```

Now, I want to select the highest amount if there are 2 same PaidDate

Please assist so I get the result as below
Result (A)

```
ID|Cust_ID|Name|Amount|  PaidDate
 2|     02|Lisa|    50|2018-03-05
 3|     01|Tina|   180|2018-03-07
```

UPDATED:
I have tried the query suggested by @Strawberry and @scaisEdge but found out new case where

```
ID|Cust_ID|Name|Amount|  PaidDate
 1|     01|Tina|   100|2018-03-07
 2|     02|Lisa|    50|2018-03-05
 3|     01|Tina|   180|2018-03-07
 4|     01|Tina|    20|2018-03-01
 5|     02|Lisa|   100|2018-03-01
```

For example, there are 2 records of Lisa here, supposed the query result as 
Result (A)
However it turns out like below because Lisa's amount is highest without looking at PaidDate first

```
ID|Cust_ID|Name|Amount|  PaidDate
 3|     01|Tina|   180|2018-03-07          
 5|     02|Lisa|   100|2018-03-01
```

The requirement is,
if PaidDate  <> NULL then
    Get PaidDate with latest value and
          if PaidDate latest value > 1
             Get PaidDate with max Amount
end if

Thanks & Regards

Comment: In the first instance, your table is fundamentally flawed. You have no PRIMARY KEY, and the inclusion of Name creates an unacceptable redundancy.

Comment: Hi @Strawberry, the table does have PK. Please find updated field above.

Comment: I seriously doubt that your primary key id would be called cust_id

Comment: Yeahh supposed to switch Cust_ID and ID

Comment: @Strawberry I swap the field name. Looks good now? This is not the real data/table btw.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table 
(payment_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,user_id INT NOT NULL
,payment_date DATE NOT NULL
,amount DECIMAL(6,2) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1,1,'2018-03-07',100),
(2,2,'2018-03-05', 50),
(3,1,'2018-03-07',180),
(4,1,'2018-03-01', 20);


SELECT x.*
  FROM my_table x 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT a.user_id
            , a.payment_date
            , MAX(a.amount) amount 
         FROM my_table a
         JOIN 
            ( SELECT user_id
                   , MAX(payment_date) payment_date
                FROM my_table 
               GROUP 
                  BY user_id 
            ) b
           ON b.user_id = a.user_id
          AND b.payment_date = a.payment_date
        GROUP  
           BY user_id
            , payment_date
     ) y 
    ON y.user_id = x.user_id 
   AND y.payment_date = x.payment_date
   AND y.amount = x.amount;
+------------+---------+--------------+--------+
| payment_id | user_id | payment_date | amount |
+------------+---------+--------------+--------+
|          2 |       2 | 2018-03-05   |  50.00 |
|          3 |       1 | 2018-03-07   | 180.00 |
+------------+---------+--------------+--------+
```

While fast to execute, because this kind of solution can become long-winded, you often see people using undocumented hacks instead, like this...

```
SELECT a.* 
  FROM 
     ( SELECT * FROM my_table ORDER BY user_id, payment_date DESC, amount DESC ) a 
 GROUP 
    BY user_id;
+------------+---------+--------------+--------+
| payment_id | user_id | payment_date | amount |
+------------+---------+--------------+--------+
|          3 |       1 | 2018-03-07   | 180.00 |
|          2 |       2 | 2018-03-05   |  50.00 |
+------------+---------+--------------+--------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

There is no guarantee that such a solution will work. Indeed, the documentation implies that it shouldn't. But in practice, it always has done (so far).

Answer (score 0):

You should use a couple of nestes subquery for grouping

```
select * from 
customer c2
inner join 
( 

    select c.name, max(c.Amount) max_amount , c.paidDate
    from Customer c
    inner join (
      select name, max(paidDate) max_paiddate
      from Customer
      group by name
    ) t on t.name  = c.name and t.max_paiddate = c.paidDate
    group by c.name, c.paidDate
) t2 on t2.name = c2.name 
        and t2.max_amount = c2.amount 
              and t2.paidDate = c2.paidDate
```

Comment: Hm, one of us needs more coffee.

Comment: @Strawberry  .. please  .. explain better  .. i have already drink a lot of coffee  but don't uderstand your suggestion .

Comment: Hi @scaisEdge I have tried your query, it does give me recent paid date with max amount. However, it removes the records without duplicate like example above, ID=02, Lisa.

Comment: Ah - coffee quota achieved

Comment: @straberry  ..morning= coffee ..  ! ?

Answer (score -1):

According to description as mentioned into above question please try executing following SQL query

```
SELECT ID,Name,max(Amount),PaidDate
    FROM `Customer` group by  ID 
    order by ID desc
```